# Display List without bullet on the specific webpage

Tags: html, css, html-lists

http://goo.gl/qTjPb

my website includes index.html,pages.php,style.css, and normal.css

above link is the specific webpage that I need the list without bullets.

the list is in case'board' in the pages.php.

I tried to use inner css and external css , both don't work.

Could you help me to figure out what's wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the end of your css file

```
.nobullets li {
    list-style-type: none!important;
}
```

you can read more about **important** rule [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :-

```
<ul class='no-bullets'>
  <li>Item 1
  <li>Item 2
</ul>


ul.no-bullets
  {
   list-style-type: none;
  }
```

here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Anurag_Sharma/dvUMJ/)

Comment: hi Anurag-Sharma  this will apply for all ul ,  I wanna the specific ul , li to not show the bullets  btw thanks

Comment: you can try adding an id to ul tag , and use #id_name in place of ul

Comment: So do `ul.noBullets` or something. Then go to the `<ul>` and change it to `<ul class="noBullets">`

Comment: @Anurag-Sharma making it a class would be better, in case there are multiple.

Comment: hi Ryan,  I tried to use class in specific ul , and add no-bullets{list-style-type:none;}   not work still

Comment: user2434428 , just try it as i gave in the answer it will work i have tested it